# Why is the HTTP request works fine in Tinker but not in the app in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, tinker

I'm trying to upload a file doing a `POST` request to an `API`. So when I test it in Tinker it works fine, it takes like 5 seconds to upload the file, but when I test my own endpoint using `Postman` I get this error:

> "message": "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded".

Not sure why is it working on Tinker fine but not in the app.

Here's how my request looks like:

```
$response = Http::attach('file', file_get_contents(asset('storage/' . $attachment->type . '/' . $attachment->name)), $attachment->name)
        ->post('https://api-example.com/endpoint', 
            [
                'uid' => env('HANDWRYTTEN_UID'),
                'type' => 'cover'
            ]);
        return $response->json();
```

I have cleared the cache and config like this

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: is `"message": "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded".` thrown by your server or the API?..

Comment: It's thrown by the server

Comment: yes but which one, your or the api's one?

Comment: lol my localhost, not the API's

Comment: are you testing with the same file?

Comment: Yes, it's the same file. It should do the same thing because the request from postman to my localhost I only send an ID, I do the same thing from Tinker. Then the method takes that ID to grab the file and upload it using the external API endpoint.

Comment: if you increase the max execution time does it ends or it doesn't work either ?

Comment: Let me try that, however, using Tinker it only takes like 5-8 seconds to upload, not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Could it be a glitch with Postman? Can you try using browser `fetch()` or other way to test the request

Comment: hmm interesting...I will try that, thank you :) @cheryllium

Comment: Hi there! For some reason I tried to change the way to send ```file_get_contents()``` and I used ```storage_path()``` instead of ```asset()``` and it worked! So maybe there was an error with the file path but I wasn't getting any errors about that. It's now solved,thank you @Berto99 and @cheryllium !

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I tried to change the way to send `file_get_contents()` and I used `storage_path()` instead of `asset()` and it worked! So maybe there was an error with the file path but I wasn't getting any errors about that. It's now solved. Thank you!